# ZXing barcode scanner to read Brazilian barcode

Tags: java, android, integration, barcode, zxing

I'm aware that there is another post with the same topic here in the forum, but I coulnd't solve my problem and I've tried everything and it doesn't work.

Here is the thing, I've tried to make barcodeScanner, from ZXing, to read barcode format interleaved 2 of 5 , in an android I'm developing, but it doesn't work. The Scanner keep with the red light in the screen but doesn't read the bar code at all.

I'm using the "android-integration-2.3.0.jar", downloaded from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/android-integration/2.3.0 , 
but it doesn't read my bar code at all. I'm sure that the problem is not with my barcode, it's an official one from a famous bank here.
This is the tutorial that I've followed :
http://techiedreams.com/android-zxing-barcode-scanner-integration/

Anyway, let me show you some code: this is how I'm invoking the barCodeScanner

ImageView ivBarCode = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPagamentosCodBar);
        ivBarCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "AZTEC,CODABAR,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,EAN_8,EAN_13,ITF,MAXICODE,PDF_417,QR_CODE,RSS_14,RSS_EXPANDED,UPC_A,UPC_E,UPC_EAN_EXTENSION");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

and This is how i'm reading the information:
or at least, think it should work:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
//      if (data == null) {
//          ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
//          return;
//      }else 
        if (requestCode==IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (scanResult != null)
            {
               String codBar = scanResult.toString();
               Toast.makeText(PagamentosContas.this, codBar, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Log.e("Código de Barras",codBar);
               Log.e("Código de Barras",codBar);
               Log.e("Código de Barras",codBar);

            }
            else
            {
                // else continue with any other code you need in the method
               Toast.makeText(PagamentosContas.this, "scanResult is null.",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
//      else{
//      String valor = data.getStringExtra("valor");
//      valor = valor.replace(",", ".");
//
//      pagamento.setValorConta(valor);
//      ThreadPagamentosContas thread1 = new ThreadPagamentosContas();
//      thread1.start();
//      ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
//      }

    }
```

it doesn't read any barcode at all, or when it does, do it wrong, took an interleaved 2 of 5 by an EAN3...

here is an example of an official barcode:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQMtFUGwDRBWnZObkFBcDR1RVk/edit

thanks in advance.
this is driving me crazy for months now...

Comment: Have you tried another bar code just for testing? Are you sure the image from the camera has sufficient resolution and contrast? I would take a few shots of barcodes, save them as images and try feeding them to the zxing command line just to see if they fail due to quality.

Comment: I've tried with a lot of devices with good cameras, and even poor cameras. The poor camera doesn't get at all, and the device with a good camera reads the barcode all wrong, even the format type. Tried already, the ZBar, FixBoletoFree, SDTBarcodeSDKForAndroid, none of then actually works. I think that maybe I was doing something wrong, but I was following the step by step guide, of all this tools. None worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem!
Everything on the tutorial is right and works fine.
The problem was the camera of ALL devices I have for testing.

Last week I've got a better smartphone, with better resources and it reads the barcode just fine.
Tablets usually don't have an autofocus tool in the camera hardware, so it cannot focus the barcode properlly.